# Highcharts fill map based on data values with React TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I'm trying to fill colours in countries based on each country's data. Something similar to [this map](https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/rich-info). Something similar to the function `formatter` in `tooltip`.

I've tried different approaches, including using `zones` (like it's described [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-zoneaxis-x/), [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.zones) and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-simple/)) but couldn't do it.

```js
import mapDataWorld from '@highcharts/map-collection/custom/world.geo.json';
import worldMapData from '../data/WorldMapData';

const options: Highcharts.Options = {
    series: [{
        type: 'map',
        mapData: mapDataWorld,
        data: worldMapData,
        // Zones don't seem to work for point value
        zones: [{
            value: 2,
            color: '#f7a35c'
        }]
    }],
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '',
        formatter: function () {
            const country = this.point;
            const info = `The value for ${country.name} is ${country.value}`
            return info;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `colorAxis`

```
const options: Highcharts.Options = {
    colorAxis: {
            dataClasses: [{
              to: 10,
              color: "red"
            }, {
              from: 10,
              to: 20,
              color: "orange"
            }, {
              from: 20,
              to: 50,
              color: "yellow"
            }]
          }
      .
      .
      .
```

[more about colorAxis](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.dataClasses)

Comment: Thank you @Alex. Let me try it. I'll get back to you.

Comment: That does it. Thank you @Alex.